# Append elem to before parent tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using `JQuery 3.2.1` and would like to append a table column with a certain value in front of a cell.

The final result should look like the following:

[image]

Find below my simplyfied viable example:

```js
const targetButton = $(".btn.btn-primary.btn-sm.motherboard")
targetButton.append(`
        <td>
            <img src="" alt="" height="42" width="42">
            <a href="">
                Test Title
            </a>
        </td>    
        `)
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="float: left;" class="table table-bordered">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>CPU</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" data-exists="cpu" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm cpu">
                                            Add CPU
                                        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Motherboard</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" data-exists="motherboard" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm motherboard">
                                            Add Motherboard
                                        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Graphic Card</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" data-exists="graphic-card" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm graphic-card">
                                            Add Graphic Card
                                        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Power Supply&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" data-exists="power-supply" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm power-supply">
                                            Add Power Supply
                                        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>More Parts&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" data-exists="more-parts" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm more-parts">
                                            Add More Parts
                                        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see the tag get directly inserted into the button. At runtime of my whole Javascript app I only have the button as a selected element available.

How can I append the code in my `append` function right before the button`s parent element?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@CertainPerformance answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49865869/3385827) is right.. And this is a jquery solution .. by using `.closest()` and `insertBefore()`

```js
const targetButton = $(".btn.btn-primary.btn-sm.motherboard").closest('td');
$('<td><img src="" alt="" height="42" width="42"><a href="">Test Title</a></td>').insertBefore(targetButton);
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="float: left;" class="table table-bordered">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>CPU</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" data-exists="cpu" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm cpu">
                                            Add CPU
                                        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Motherboard</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" data-exists="motherboard" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm motherboard">
                                            Add Motherboard
                                        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Graphic Card</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" data-exists="graphic-card" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm graphic-card">
                                            Add Graphic Card
                                        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Power Supply&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" data-exists="power-supply" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm power-supply">
                                            Add Power Supply
                                        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>More Parts&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" data-exists="more-parts" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm more-parts">
                                            Add More Parts
                                        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Select the target button's parent element first:

```js
const targetButton = $(".btn.btn-primary.btn-sm.motherboard")
const targetButtonParent = targetButton[0].parentElement;
targetButtonParent.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', `
        <td>
            <img src="" alt="" height="42" width="42">
            <a href="">
                Test Title
            </a>
        </td>    
        `)
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="float: left;" class="table table-bordered">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>CPU</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" data-exists="cpu" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm cpu">
                                            Add CPU
                                        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Motherboard</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" data-exists="motherboard" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm motherboard">
                                            Add Motherboard
                                        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Graphic Card</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" data-exists="graphic-card" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm graphic-card">
                                            Add Graphic Card
                                        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Power Supply&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" data-exists="power-supply" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm power-supply">
                                            Add Power Supply
                                        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>More Parts&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" data-exists="more-parts" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm more-parts">
                                            Add More Parts
                                        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```